# structure for managing tenant accounts from an admin account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, architecture, rails-api, apartment-gem

I'm trying to create an API for a multi tenancy web app using Rails 5.

But i'm in trouble figuring out an application structure that would allow us to do this:

- we don't want to enable users to register themselves to obtain their organization's account, but to have people from our staff to create them internally.
- The staff should send invitations to each organization's platform administrator, enabling them to complete the registration process, allowing them to invite their own users in. that invitation url to register will be already subdomained and records created within their own database schema (postgres)
- From the organization's admin starts an hierarchy of roles that restrict access to different resources and actions.

I'm not feeling comfortable with giving a super-admin-like role to one user of the same user model to complete that task.

Should i need to create two different models for each kind of user, leaving one (the "system admins") on the public schema, to spin a separated admin interface?

That seems a little odd to me, but maybe it's right.
(having two different models with the same purpose of persist, identify, and manage platform's user credentials)

Also i don't want to leave user accounts out in the public schema without a good reason, and the case of one user belonging to more than one organization is very unlikely to happen in the application's context. (and separate accounts are preferable)

...So my question is:

**What could be a proper/good application structure to allow the staff to manage the creation of the tenancy accounts internally?**

Comment: What you mean by "leave on/in the public schema"? The database that an organization's admins see regarding their users?

Comment: the database that doesn't belong to a tenant. like saying database.table instead of database.another_schema.table
[docs 5.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-schemas.html)